# How to raise an army against the dark lord when everyone thinks he was already defeated?

Tags: society, warfare

A long time ago there was a vast prosperous kingdom, with magic and steampunk-level technology. But secretly, an evil mage, whom we will call the "Dark Lord" was using forbidden magic to build power. One day the Dark Lord finished writing a spell that would give him enough power to take over the entire world, and then he attacked. Any mage who tried to take him on found themselves outmatched, entire armies fell in an instant, and towns and villages across the land were destroyed. The most powerful mages, who worked in the king's court hatched a plan to stop the Dark Lord, they would find the strongest warrior in the land, henceforth known as The Chosen One, and enhance his abilities with magic. Blacksmiths across the land began working on crafting a weapon worthy of being wielded by such a powerful being, and all remaining mages gathered together to cast the spell. All remaining military was called up to protect the Chosen One, and with some genius military strategy, as well as the sacrifice of many brave men and women, they managed to open up a hole in the Dark Lord's defense. The Chosen One then launched an attack that was strong enough to defeat the weakened Dark Lord. As the Dark Lord fell, he foretold his return. The Chosen One spread the news that the Dark Lord would return, but as time passed on, the story became a legend, then a myth, truly believed by no one, except for the Chosen One's descendants.

How would the Chosen One's descendants gather up an army large enough to defeat the Dark Lord when he returns when everyone believes the Dark Lord was beaten for good hundreds of years ago?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are and there have always been two and only two ways to raise an army: ideology, and money, either real money (e.g. the American army) or expected money (e.g., Genghis Khan). So either you go *allons enfants de la patrie, le jour de gloire est arrivé*, or you go *join the army and get good money, good food, and the opportunity to see the world and plunder its wealth*. There is no third option.

Comment: Surely it is your job, as the author, to come up with plot points for your work? "_help me build my world_" is slightly different to "_please write my plot_".

Comment: This is giving off Voldemort Vibes....

Comment: This is all for the history books, the actual story is taking place after the Dark Lord is defeated for the second time.

Comment: But if no one knows when the time will come that The Dark Lord Rises, why would they want to raise an army now? And if they do know, wouldn't that be enough of an incentive for an army to form?

Comment: Does the hero know when the bad guy will return, or is he trying to organize a standing army that will stay mobilized for centuries?

Comment: VTC: From the [help/on-topic], "When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, **not to tell your story.**" This question is asking us to create a plot point, not to develop a world rule. World rules exist independent of all stories. Storybuilding has no right answer, is brainstorming, open-ended, and hypothetical, all of which is prohibited (see [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Infiltrate other governments and bureaucracies

To influence people you need power. From the moment the dark lord falls they should be setting up an order to stop him. They should be using the vast concentration of magical resources to build weapons for the next chosen one, prepare kingdoms to have a stronger infrastructure to stop evil mages, work to build regulations to destroy sources of forbidden magic and generally make a more prepared world.

This would self propagate in the same way many secret orders do. It would be a secret society where you have fun rituals, robes, and traditions where if you're a member you're better placed to advance in society. Not everyone will believe all the religious mumbo jumbo about a dark lord, but everyone knows the benefits of having friends in high places.

## Prepare a war chest

War is expensive. They should be preparing magic, weapons, food, bandages, all the supplies needed to wage a war. They can sell the surplus or old goods to increase their profit. With all the world's mages and blacksmiths allied they should have a lot of room to get a strong start.

If you can, become the bank of the world. Fund research, wars, and kings so that everyone is in debt to your group.

## Encourage nations to have wars that follow codes of chivalry or honour

Once they have lots of money, weapons, and influence they should encourage nations to have strong armies. Encourage play wars, encourage wars that don't cause too many deaths. Build up your populations, colonize new places, and build up a world that is strong enough to fight back.

## Cash it all in

Eventually the dark lord will come. Cash in all the favours, call in all the influence you have, spend money like it's water from the sky. It's time to go to war.

Answer (score 2):

## Start a War

[image]

Need an army? Start a war.

Say the guys over there are bad. They are a threat to our **national security**. They are a threat to our **liberty** and **freedom**. They have **weapons of mass destruction**. Like the ones we have? Yes, but only not as good. And we are allowed to have them. We are the **good guys** after all. Now shut your trap you commie sympathiser.

[image]

Once you have murdered the other guys and taken their stuff, your army will be well supplied and experienced killing things. Ready to kill the dark lord when he comes back.

Answer (score 0):

### Cause distrust between kingdoms/regions/provinces to orchestrate a arms race

The "dark lord" is a vague and far away threat. However, there are other nations nearby that are genuine nearby threats. And distrust is easy to create.

Spreading rumors is easy, just say things like:

- I heared that nation X has a entire school for developing more powerful offensive spells
- Did you know nation Y has over 200 magical catapults just on standby?
- Nation Z is building outposts all over the desert near our border.

In response, governments and people, in fear, will be more willing investing time and money getting their own military up to level, each trying to out-compete to become the strongest. Hopefully without ever actually fighting.

When the dark lord attacks, hopefully, all the armies can cooperate to take them down.