# Why would a dangerous form of magic be kept alive in a post-apocalyptical scenario?

Tags: magic, post-apocalypse

This question is in the same universe as my last one, [How to raise an army against the dark lord when everyone thinks he was already defeated?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/239626/how-to-raise-an-army-against-the-dark-lord-when-everyone-thinks-he-was-already-d)
In this universe, magic is powered by the energy of thought, and if you don't have enough thought energy stored somewhere on you, spells will drain your energy, killing you in the process. After the Dark Lord from the previous question was defeated for the first time, remember the story takes place after the second time, he left the world in a post-apocalyptic state.

Why would anybody risk using and learning magic, if life is just a constant struggle to survive, and learning magic just adds another way for you to die?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: VTC: [As mentioned in your first question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/239626/how-to-raise-an-army-against-the-dark-lord-when-everyone-thinks-he-was-already-d#comment733933_239626), posts about storybuilding (plot, circumstances, character choices, etc.) are ***off-topic.*** If you can't strip the story from the question and still have a valid question, it's not appropriate here.

Answer (score 3):

**Necessity.**

If we think back to technology considered dangerous in the past, it was still used because *other* people were going to use it, so if you didn't use it you would be left behind. Think about your magic system. If this is a post apocalypse, survival needs will be quite important. If your magic can help in this regard, in acquiring food, water, natural resources, and especially in defense, it would be pretty useful.

It sounds like, if I am correct, that you may have the concern that after magic caused this cataclysm for everyone, they wouldn't want to use it after so much pain. In this case then I'd simply make a note of saying that the people have misgivings about magic, but they need to use it. You may also deflect the resentment away from the magic itself, and have them direct their anger towards this dark lord instead.

But yeah, that's generally what you want to focus on, fine tuning your world where magic gives a big advantage. If this is in a post apocalypse, it isn't like there's a super large culture influencing people to not want to use this, though perhaps you'd see a lot of diverging views on magic in different tribes and clans.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea, I really like it.

Comment: @Wizardchris842 if you provided more details on the capabilities of your magic, that would be helpful.

Comment: I will soon but I have to go do something right now.

Comment: Please do not answer questions that are off-topic. From the [help/on-topic], (a) "When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story" and (b) "If on the other hand you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site" and (c) "If you are looking for discussion, brainstorming, or an overall process rather than specific questions and answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question."

Comment: @JBH - I had an answer for their question and was able to help. I don't see what's wrong with that but alright.

Comment: @WasatchWind Please read the following two Help Center pages: [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]. There are questions we don't host. Usually I'm not such a nudge about it, but this OP has asked two questions within a few hours of each other and was clearly told on the first one that this kind of question is off-topic for this Stack.